# Ulpan class for non-Jews?

Tags: language, israel

[SmartAsset](https://smartasset.com/retirement/retire-in-israel) says:

> The course, known as an Ulpan, is an intensive, five-month process.
> It’s designed to help you to assimilate into the Israeli lifestyle as
> well as master the Hebrew language.

The page also says it is free.  However, the page is apparently written for *olim* (immigrants who are Jewish).

Are these classes offered to non-Jews who are legal immigrants?  Free, or at what cost?

Comment: I'm still researching, but so far, every page I've looked at assumes that no one who isn't a Jew ever wants to go to Israel.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-post, answered here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173808/hebrew-language-class-in-israel

Comment: Asked here as a potential immigrant/expat (but not Jewish) as indicated by the words "legal immigrants".  Asked there as a potential short-term visitor as indicated by the mention of "non-immigrant" and the A/2 visa.  Two similar questions but _not_ the same and thus not a "cross-post."  Each would no doubt be dubbed off-topic if posted on the other stack.

Comment: There are no non-Jews legal immigrants per se. Non-Jews can become Olim if they arrive by Law of Return, or become permanent residents through other means, but that would mean they've already lived in the country for a while.

Comment: Becoming a permanent resident, _is_ becoming an immigrant.

Comment: Yeah, but by the time you become a permanent resident in Israel, you should already know Hebrew. IIRC you have to stay as a "temporary resident" at least 3 years before you can apply for permanent residency, in some cases longer.

Comment: In any case, the answer is exactly the same, no matter what your status is. If you're not Oleh - you got to pay, and yes, there are Ulpanim that allow you to join if you pay your own tuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know people who have attended the Ulpan Hebrew workshop and are not Jewish - but they immigrated to Israel as spouses (not necessarily married) to citizens. Specifically, you might be eligible as an applicant for a B1 visa. **edit:** If you've not gained Israeli citizenship, it will cost you. I'm not sure if the rates are uniform, but it can be several thousand NIS. It's pretty intensive with hundreds of hours, so it's not that expensive I guess.